# linux find file and create hardlink

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to find a file, then create a hard link with the same name in a different directory. But this is not working, if I take the -exec and after off, it displays one result. I already have it working with cp, but I've decided to make a hard link instead.

```
find . -iname "*sample*" -exec link {} ~/{} \;
```

Comment: Is the target directory on the same physical device as the source?  Hard links cannot span mount points.

Comment: @shellter The script works fine up until "link {} ~/{} \;". Nothing happens.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes it is. I only have one hard drive.

Comment: @DavidCuster : Do you get an error message? Based on the error message I'm getting I think we need a way to remove any leading path info that is returned from a subdir find.

Comment: Can you try to to mask the bracktes like this: `-exec link "{}" ~/"{}" \;` This might have to do with the shell you use and how this is expanded.

Comment: If you replace link with cp and remove the second {}, then it works fine. But I replaced cp with link, then added the second {} because from what I understand you use link like "link file1 file2".

Comment: @vlz I just tried that, but it did not work.

Comment: yes but find is returning values like `./local/mysample` and then trying to create a link as `/home/shellter/./local/mysample`. I don't think you want to make a `local` dir under your home.

Comment: @shellter I had the same idea as you. Using `-execdir` instead of `-exec` would solve this.

Comment: the best solution would be to make a script that trims leading path info as needed, and then runs `link ./path/to/mysample $HOME/mysample`. Good luck.

Comment: ah, there you go. Thanks @gniourf_gniourf!  (Edited my comment, now "yes but **find** is returning ..." )

Comment: @shellter No I don't. You are correct! How do I get around this? My values is ./folder1/folder2/a-b-c.mkv

Comment: All set david? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter That did not work actually. :(

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf -execdir did not work.

Comment: Then the problem lies somewhere else. 1. Do you get any error message? 2. Does it work if you execute the command by hand? e.g., `link ./file_sample ~/./file_sample`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf No, it does not. I need to link /path1/file1 /path2/file1

Comment: By the way, do you have the `ln` utility available? `ln` makes hard links too.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yea, I do! :)

Comment: With `ln`: `find . -iname "*sample*" -exec ln {} ~ \;`. You haven't answered: does it work when you do it by hand: `link ./file_sample ~/./file_sample`? or `ln ./file_sample ~`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf No it does not work. I'll try your top solution right now, hold on.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Neither work. :(

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? do you get any error messages (it seems that no). What's the return code of the command?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Sorry, I do not get any error message, or any message for that matter. How would I print {} I would like to know what is in there lol Because it works with mv, cp, etc..

Comment: To print `{}` just put `-print` before the `-exec` statement.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf You would think that -exec ln {} ~ \; would work.

Comment: If it doesn't work by hand, it won't work in the `find` command. Did you actually try any of these _by hand_?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf find . -name "bla" ...finds the file but if I do find . -name "bla" -print -exec ln {} ~ \; ...it does not print

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64262/discussion-between-gniourf-gniourf-and-david-custer).

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that `{}` contains the path of the file found; hence `~/{}` is not a path in `~` but in some nonexistent sub-directory.

I didn't find a way to get the `{}` basename using `find` neither `xargs`.

Here is one solution, which works but is unsafe:

```
find . -iname "*sample*" | while read f ; do link "$f" "$HOME/${f##*/}" ; done
```

You may add a filter between `find` and `read` to get rid of "dangerous" file names.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem, as it didn't work either with `-execdir` and no error messages are issued.

Comment: @EdouardThiel link: cannot create link ‘~/file’ to ‘./folder1/folder2/file’: No such file or directory

Comment: @DavidCuster Are you joking?? from the beginning you're saying you don't have any error messages!

Comment: Re: basename: `find . -iname '*sample*' -exec bash -c 'link "$0" ~/"${0##*/}"' {} \;`. By the way, `~/` should not be inside quotes, otherwise it's not expanded by the shell.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I swear, the only time I have gotten a message was when I used this command. I wonder if before it was hard linking to /home/user.

Comment: @DavidCuster Sure, you're having an error here because the `~/` is inside quotes, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I remove the quotes, and it made the hard link. Now how could I do that just using -exec ln {} ~ \;

Comment: I hate he strange behaviour of `~`. Replaced with `$HOME`.

Comment: @EdouardThiel can you please upvote OP's question so that he has 20+ rep and we can move to chat room?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Why doesn't  -exec ln {} $HOME \; work?

Comment: @DavidCuster You now have 20+ rep, please join the chat room.